# No graphical option while using Debian 8 netinst install

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

I have been trying to install Debian 8 on my machine using the netinst liveUSB.

Everything goes alright except the fact that when the installer asks me which packages I want to install in the Software Selection part. In that part there's only the "Standard System Utilities" option, instead of the usual "Graphical desktop environment" and some others. So, proceeding with this installation will only install the core of the system and no GUI.

Am I missing something here?

PS.: I'm using mirrors.
Thank you.

Comment: This question is Debian specific, not UNIX or Linux...

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this question. Just as @Rubatharisan said, there are plenty of questions here that deal with Debian. Where else do you suggest I post this?

Comment: I would suggest http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ (if it is for professional usage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The netinst liveUSB does not include any GUI. As far as I know, you have two options: (1) install the current core system, and install a graphical user manager afterwards, or (2) install another version of debian which contains a GUI on the USB.

(1) - Install the core system and install a graphical environment - this could be: Gnome, KDE, Xfce or ay other. See more at https://wiki.debian.org/DesktopEnvironment

Those graphical environment have different focus areas, for example: xfce is lightweight, and you would install xfce on a machine that have low ram. KDE is fancy, you would install KDE if you need eyecandy. Gnome is just Gnome, simple and just straightforward - with an mix of everything.

(2) - Reinstall the usb with a debian.iso that contains a graphical environment.

Edit: There is nothing wrong with your question. I would ignore Vinz, some people have pleasure of hating.

Edit 2: To Vinz, go write a comment to these questions, and tell them that they are too Debian specific - now where you are at it:
[Debian stucks at formatting 33%](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46060/debian-stucks-at-formatting-33?rq=1) 
[How can I install only the basics in Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132640/how-can-i-install-only-the-basics-in-debian?rq=1)
[Debian "Graphical expert install" mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154264/debian-graphical-expert-install-mode?rq=1)

Sorry Tom for me making the edits, it's because I can't comment yet.

Comment: I didn't know they excluded the GUI! Pardon my ignorance, but how can I tell if the .iso has a GUI included?

Comment: If you use 64 bit architecture, visit: http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/ - and download the ones with gnome/kde/xfce as the end of the name: for example: 

debian-live-8.2.0-amd64-gnome-desktop.iso

If you use 32 bit architecture, visit: 
http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/i386/iso-hybrid/ and download one named: 
debian-live-8.2.0-i386-gnome-desktop.iso

They are normally called this: 
debian-live-version-arch-desktopenviroment-type.iso (Sorry for my slow response)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had come across those files and yet I failed to conclude that since they had the desktops in their names they must include the desktop env! Pretty logical, though. I'm already download cinnamon version. And thanks for that last edit about the comment ;). Too bad I got a -1 anyway.

Comment: You are most welcome :) Hehe indeed it is logical, but I have been exactly where you are, and spent countless of hours of getting it right ;) (That was the time with no SSD's). Have fun with Debian, and I hope you'll enjoy it! :D

Comment: @RubatharisanThirumathyam: I'm not hating, I just review some posts and I consider this one off-topic. This is not a Debian forum... We're here to discuss Unix & Linux. So questions like "how can I do to install a package on Debian/Ubuntu/whatever ?" shouldn't be asked here. This is just my opinion, no hate. I left a comment because I downvoted his question, and I try to always tell why I downvote. See... no hate...

Comment: @Vinz, please - this guy is new to Debian, and instead of giving him these kind of negative attitude, why not help him out and let him enjoy Debian?
Tom, if you aint new to Debian, then I am so sorry :)

Comment: Because it's not the right place, that's all. I've flagged the question, we'll see if the moderators agree with that flag or not. If not, I won't flag this kind of questions anymore.

Comment: There are plenty of distro-specific questions here. Nothing wrong with that; it's tagged correctly. Should the `/debian` tag be prohibited also then?